# PHP form not submitting

Tags: php, html, forms, post

For one reason or another, I cannot get my PHP form to post. I tried running print statements in login.php and nothing yielded.

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" id="loginForm">
<div class="input-prepend login-input">
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>
    <input class="span2" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email address" required>
</div>

<div class="input-prepend login-input">
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-key"></i></span>
    <input class="span2" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    <!--<i class="icon-eye-open password" id="eye"></i>-->
</div>

<input class="btn btn-primary login-input" id="loginButton" type="submit" value="Login"/>
<input class="btn btn-small login-input" id="cancelButton" type="button" value="Cancel"/>
</form>
```

When I submit the form, absolutely nothing happens, why would that be?  Here is my login.php:

```
<?php 
include 'core/init.php';

if(empty($_POST) === false){

$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

#HTML5 should have checked this, just as an extra precaution 
if(empty($email) || empty($password)){
    $errors[] = "Please enter your email and password";
}
else if(user_exists($email) === false){
    $errors[] = "User does not exist";
}
else if(user_active($email) === false){
    $errors[] = "Your account has not been activated"
}
else{
    #log in the user
}
print_r($errors);
}

?>
```

Comment: Do you have the form start tag ?

Comment: Must have missed it in copy/pasting: <form action="login.php" method="post" id="loginForm"> @DanielStutz

Comment: It was there, but there was an issue with the code formatting. Fixed.

Comment: Are you sure that the page that displays the form is in the same directory as login.php?

Comment: You said "absolutely nothing happens." I assume that you mean no output is generated. In its current form, output will only be generated by your code if validation errors are present in your form. Otherwise, it will run silently. Try adding an `echo` statement to verify that your code block is executing.

Comment: The form is in a subdirectory while the login.php file is in the root. I'm guessing this is causing an issue?

Comment: @wesley.ireland Most definitely

Comment: @wesley.ireland I tried your code. If the login.php is not found, there should be an error message. I think George Cummings is right. When I put in the else area an echo, that the login was successfull, then is an output to see.

Comment: If the form is in a subdirectory, and `login.php` is in the root, you need to change your form action to the root - ie. `<form action="../login.php" ...` or `<form action="http://website.com/login.php" ...`

Answer (score 2):

Did you inspect network with chrome inspector when submitting your form ?

This will allow you to display request headers and POST data.

just make this to display if your data is here :

```
<pre><?php var_dump($_POST);?></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you change the type of  tag from 'button' to 'submit', then it may work.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<input class="btn btn-primary login-input" id="loginButton" type="submit" name="loginForm" value="Login"/>

        if (isset($_POST["loginForm"])) {
            //execute the code
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

The following adjustment to the HTML code should fix your issue and actually POST to the **login.php** component:

```
<form action="/login.php" method="post" id="loginForm">
```

Notice the */* (forward slash) added to the front of the **login.php** string in the action HTML attribute.